# Ler um arquivo em php

Tags: php

A minha tela, consegue listar os arquivos como link  e até exibe em outra aba com o target  ,só não consigo fazer com que o arquivo clicado exiba o conteúdo.

Estou usando o `fopen`para abrir e o `fread` para ler...

Segue como está o código:

```
<?php

   foreach(new DirectoryIterator('C:\xampp\htdocs\testtoclassificados\log') as $fileInfo){

       if($fileInfo->isDot())continue;
       if($fileInfo->isFile()){ 

       $arquivo  = $fileInfo->getPathname(); 

       if($fileInfo->isReadable() == true){
         $fp       = fopen($arquivo,"r");
        $texto    = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo));
         fclose($fp);
          echo"<li><a href='".$arquivo."' target='_blank'>".$arquivo."</a>
          <br/></li>";
       }else echo "O arquivo ".$arquivo." não possuí permissão de leitura.";
      }
   }         
  ?>
```

Exibe estes erros,quando uso o fopen e fread:

```
Warning: fopen(.): failed to open stream: Permission denied in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\testtoclassificados


Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Warning: fopen(apostila2.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\testtoclassificados
```

A lógica do código está errada?

Minha tela só que não abre outra aba com o conteúdo do arquivo...

[image: listagem]

Comment: Ricardo confere as permissões e usuario da pasta e arquivos contidos dentro de testtoclassificados. O erro em questão refere-se a isso.

Comment: Em seguida adicione essa lógica após seu foreach if ($fileinfo->isFile())  para certificar que é um arquivo antes de ler com fopen. A olho nú sem teste foi o que percebi.

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isFile() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\testtoclassificados\` esta mensagem exibe  depois que coloquei o isFile mostra que estar nulo

Comment: Eu botei if ($fileinfo->isFile()) no comments, e você no seu código usou $fileInfo com letra maiúscula no info verifica lá no seu código.

Comment: Só uma duvida, porque usar fopen dentro do iterador? A variavel texto parece não servir pra nada `$texto`.

Comment: Porque anteriormente ele estava imprimindo um pedaço do texto de chamariz na tela. Não sei se ele vai manter isso!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para entender melhor o problema, você pode adicionar um depurador no seu código dessa forma.

```
<?php
    foreach(new DirectoryIterator('C:\xampp\htdocs\testtoclassificados\log') as $fileInfo){
       echo "<pre>"; print_r($fileInfo); echo "</pre>";
       /*$fp = fopen($fileInfo,"r");
       $texto = fread($fp, filesize($fileInfo));
       if($fileInfo->isDot())continue;
       $arqName = $fileInfo->getFilename();  
       // $handle = $fileInfo->fopen("c:\\data\\info.txt", "r");*/
    }
?>
```

Utilize o print_r para printar na tela a instância da classe DirectoryIterator retornada por cada interação de seu loop foreach. Cada objeto printado é um arquivo ou diretorio dentro do diretório log. Você está utilizando a instância do objeto fileInfo como path para o arquivo e na realidade é uma instancia de objeto com métodos e atributos. Siga o exemplos da documentação [DirectoryIterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.directoryiterator.php) Em seguida remova o comentário que adicionei e verifique qual o último arquivo ou diretório que o código php  exibe a mensagem de erro.  Verifique se não  está tentando usar o fopen em um diretório. Tem que validar a condição para o fopen ler apenas arquivos.

```
<?php
    foreach(new DirectoryIterator('C:\xampp\htdocs\testtoclassificados\log') as $fileInfo){
           //Se for . ou .. pular para a próxima interação do laço.               
           if($fileInfo->isDot())continue;
           if($fileInfo->isFile()){
               //DirectoryIterator::getPathname — Retorna o caminho e o nome 
               //do arquivo do elemento atual do diretório
               $arquivo  = $fileInfo->getPathname(); 
               // Abre para leitura mas antes verifica se o arquivo
               // tem permissão de leitura.
               if($fileInfo->isReadable() == true){
                  $fp       = fopen($arquivo,"r");
                  $texto    = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo));
                  echo $texto."<br/><br/>";
                  fclose($fp);
              }else echo "O arquivo ".$arquivo." não possuí permissão de leitura.";  
          }
    }
?>
```

Para fazer uma listagem de arquivos com links e abrir em nova guia faça assim :

```
<?php
    foreach(new DirectoryIterator('C:\xampp\htdocs\testtoclassificados\log') as $fileInfo){
      //Se for . ou .. pular para a próxima interação do laço.               
      if($fileInfo->isDot())continue;
        if($fileInfo->isFile()){
          //DirectoryIterator::getPathname — Retorna o caminho e o nome 
          //do arquivo do elemento atual do diretório
          $arquivo  = $fileInfo->getPathname(); 
          // Abre para leitura mas antes verifica se o arquivo
          // tem permissão de leitura.
          if($fileInfo->isReadable() == true){
              $fp       = fopen($arquivo,"r");
              $texto    = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo));
              fclose($fp);
              // A variavel $arquivo recebeu o valor do método contido 
              //dentro da intância da classe DirectoryInterator.
              //Dentro desse objeto existe o método que retorna o caminho 
              //completo até o arquivo, como mostrado abaixo
              //$fileInfo->getPathname(), portanto a variavel $arquivo possuí 
              //o path completo uma vez que definida acima.
              $urlLeitor  = "http://localhost/leitor.php?arquivo=".$fileInfo->getFilename(); 
              echo"<li><a href='".$urlLeitor."' target='_blank'>".$texto."</a>
              <br/></li>";
           }else echo "O arquivo ".$arquivo." não possuí permissão de leitura.";  
       }
    }
?>
```

Comment: O rafael ficou bom mesmo do jeito que você  postou. Agora  eu gostaria  nesta mesma página  quando clico no arquivo ela abre em outra página.. mostrando o conteúdo do arquivo.

Comment: Não entendi edita seu comentário. Você usou no seu link target='_blank' vai sempre abrir em nova guia. O que quer fazer?

Comment: ` <li><?php echo "<a href=\"$fileInfo\" target=\"_blank\">$fileInfo</a><br>"?></li> do jeito que estar ,mostra arquivo não encontrado..404 quando abre em outra aba
`

Comment: Expliquei acima $fileInfo não é o path para seu arquivo é uma instância da classe DirectoryInterator para obter o path completo para o arquivo use 
$fileInfo->getPathname(). Vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: Certo Rafael entendi..  só que do jeito que estar o conteúdo aparece como link e na mesma página,eu quero o nome do arquivo que estar em uma pasta e quando clico abre outra aba com o conteudo .. tipo : notas.txt e abre em outra aba as notas entendeu do jeito que estar aparece na mesma . Desculpa exigir tanto ainda estou verde em php

Comment: Tá assim e exibe erro 404 `<li><?php echo "<a href=\"arquivo\" target=\"_blank\">$fileInfo</a><br>"?></li>
`

Comment: se colocar conforme o exemplo no meu aki aparece o conteúdo na pagina e como link ,mas que não abre a outra aba

Comment: Mas você deveria substituir o c:\xamp\htdocs por http://localhost se está executando pelo navegador. Nunca testei no xamp mas eu acredito que pelo caminho local deve haver algum bloqueio. Faça um replace usando a função str_replace. Ou antes tente abrir o arquivo pelo seu navegador com http://localhost/testtoclassificados/log/classe1.txt veja o que acontece.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/log/classe1.txt` assim com o meu xampp ativado com o apache ele exibe  o conteúdo do arquivo...

Comment: e outra.. a pasta com os arquivos só aparece o nome conforme a imagem se ela estiver dentro da pasta do projeto.. se não diz que nao pode encontrar o caminho especificado....  os erros sempre apontam prá cá  ` foreach(new DirectoryIterator('localhost\testtoclassificados\startbootstrap-full-slider-gh-pages\log'`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70411/discussion-between-rafael-salomao-and-ricardo-mendes).